# Get data from the last 8 hours in a datetime column Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, datetime

I have a query using Laravel's Eloquent and I need a `where` clause that will get the data from the last 8 hours since the current timestamp. I can easily do that in a raw query like:

```
SELECT * FROM task_tracker.tasks WHERE created_at > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -8 HOUR);
```

But how do I do that in an eloquent format? The `tasks.created_at` is a Datetime Format. I have this currently:

```
$tasks = Task::join('users', 'tasks.added_by', '=', 'users.id')
        ->join('users AS x', 'x.id', '=', 'tasks.assigned_to')
        ->select([
          'tasks.id',
          'tasks.task_description',
          'tasks.start_timestamp',
          'tasks.end_timestamp',
          'tasks.status',
          'users.name',
          'x.name AS assign',
          'tasks.created_at'
         // ])->where('tasks.created_at', '>', 'DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -8 HOUR)');
          ])->where(DB::raw('tasks.created_at', '=', 'DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -8 HOUR)' ));

        dd($tasks);
```

I tried using `DB::raw` and a plain encloure in a single quote (the commented line) but does not work and doesn't get any data. I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DB::raw` has one parameter so try `whereRaw` like this:

`->whereRaw('tasks.created_at = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -8 HOUR')`

Comment: I will revert the -1 when the single quote will be added to the snippet

Comment: Yup, missed that. Done ;)