# eloquent fetch records within recent 3 hours

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need to fetch all the records which is inserted between past 3 hours to current(now).  I am using laravel framework(eloquent orm).

I tried this found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36912349/get-data-from-the-last-8-hours-in-a-datetime-column-eloquent/36912457#36912457)

```
$lb = \DB::table('myTable')->whereRaw('created_at = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -3 HOUR');
```

But it return NULL. Is there any way I can do using eloquent but not Raw Query?

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does [this link](http://laravel.io/forum/04-02-2014-selecting-all-records-created-last-month-with-eloquent) help you?

Comment: You miss " ) " try : whereRaw('created_at = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -3 HOUR)')

Comment: Try This 
$lb = \DB::table('myTable')->whereRaw('created_at between now() and DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 HOUR)');

Comment: It should be `>=` instead of `=`. And also missing `)`.

Comment: @rad11 output is same. 'Null''

Comment: although, there is a record within that period

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Laravel comes with Carbon, a nice library to handle dates, which can be used in combination with Eqlouent.

**Example:**

```
\DB::table('myTable')
    ->where('created_at', '>', 
        Carbon::now()->subHours(3)->toDateTimeString()
    );
```

**More Information**

For more fun date methods, check out these docs on Carbon
http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub

Comment: @Ali Seyfi why the edit changing it from whereDate to where?

Comment: i dont exactly know, but it didnt work with whereDate and worked with where when i executed the code

Comment: @AliSeyfi The solution I posted is tested and documented - which is _probably_ better for future readers than an edit that you don't know why it worked....

Comment: But if you can't explain why my version didn't work - especially considering its a documented Laravel feature, I don't understand why you would change it. Anyway, your call, it got approved

Answer (score 9):

We can use PHP `DateTime`. Like this,

```
$date = new \DateTime();
$date->modify('-3 hours');
$formatted_date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$lb = \DB::table('myTable')->where('created_at', '>',$formatted_date);
```

In above code what we're doing is creating date string with PHP and using that in query.

Comment: this query is showing syntax error. `syntax error, unexpected '3'`

Comment: We can also do the same using PHP DateTime, try my second method if you're allowed to do so.

Comment: Finally the second method works fine. Thanks @Alok Patel

Answer (score 4):

add this scope to your model:

```
public function scopeRecent($query)
{
    return $query-> whereDate('created_at ' , '=',Carbon::today())
        ->whereTime('created_at' , '>',Carbon::now()->subHours(3));

}
```

then use the scope in controller :

```
    $posts= Post::recent()->pluck("id")->toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$lb = \DB::table('myTable')->whereRaw('created_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 HOUR)')
```

In your statement you are using `=` (206-07-27 11:30:00) instead `>=` (206-07-27 11:30:00)

Comment: this query always returns null either I changes the hour value to more or less.

Answer (score 0):

try this,
include `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` namespace in your controller

and try this code

```
$results = DB::table('yourtable')->select('*')->where('created_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR)')->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

as created_at is datetime field, you can use this

```
\DB::table('myTable')->where('created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subHours(3)->toDateTimeString())->get();
```